# Необходимо сделать из изображения карту

Tags: android, карты

Есть изображение (пример: [ТЫК](https://vk.cc/67hmz8))
Необходимо сделать из этого изображения своеобразную карту
Функции зума, перемещения и тд.
Перерыл гугл, не нашел ничего подобного, мб тут есть кто может помочь мне
P.S: если это работает на тайлах, то объясните как это делается, ничего не понятно :(

Заранее спасибо:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `WebView` для отображения картинки. Закиньте её в `res/drawable` например с именем `map`. В разметке создайте `WebView`

```
<WebView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webMap"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Найдите его в `java` в методе `onCreate()` после `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, где `main` это разметка с `WebView`.

```
WebView map = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webMap);
```

Потом загружайте картинку

```
map.loadUrl("file://res/drawable/map");
```

Для зума используйте

```
map.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам необходимо просто отобразить высоко детализированное изображение с возможностью зума и перемещения, то можно воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками, например, [`ImageViewZoom`](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) или [`PhotoView`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). Как минимум, потребление ресурсов должно быть меньше, чем у `WebView`.